# How can I derive the rotation matrix from the axis-angle rotation vector?

Tags: math, robotics

Given an axis-angle rotation vector $\Theta = (2,2,0)$, after finding the unit vector $k=(1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}, 0)$ and angle $\theta = 2\sqrt{2}$ representing the same rotation, I need to derive the rotation matrix $R$ representing the same rotation and to show, that the matrix is orthonormal. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) $R_k(\theta)$ associated with a given unit-length vector $k$ and angle $\theta$ is given by the following formula

$$\small{R_k(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} 
\cos \theta +k_x^2 \left(1-\cos \theta\right) & k_x k_y \left(1-\cos \theta\right) - k_z \sin \theta & k_x k_z \left(1-\cos \theta\right) + k_y \sin \theta \\ 
k_y k_x \left(1-\cos \theta\right) + k_z \sin \theta & \cos \theta + k_y^2\left(1-\cos \theta\right) & k_y k_z \left(1-\cos \theta\right) - k_x \sin \theta \\ 
k_z k_x \left(1-\cos \theta\right) - k_y \sin \theta & k_z k_y \left(1-\cos \theta\right) + k_x \sin \theta & \cos \theta + k_z^2\left(1-\cos \theta\right)
\end{bmatrix}}$$

So, to find your specific rotation matrix, you just need to substitute the values of your $k$ and $\theta$ in the above matrix.

The derivation of this matrix can be found in section *9.2 Rotation Matrix Derivation* of the PhD thesis [*Modelling CPV* (2015)](https://dspace.lboro.ac.uk/dspace-jspui/handle/2134/18050), by Ian R. Cole. The basic idea of the derivation follows the following steps

1. Rotate the given axis $k$ and the point $p$ (that you want to rotate) such that the axis $k$ lies in one of the coordinate **planes**: xy, yz or zx
2. Rotate the given axis $k$ and the point $p$ (that you want to rotate) such that the axis $k$ is aligned with one of the two coordinate ***axes** for that particular coordinate **plane***: $x$, $y$ or $z$
3. Use one of the [fundamental rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to rotate the point $p$ depending on the coordinate axis with which the rotation axis is aligned
4. Reverse rotate the axis-point pair such that it attains the final configuration as that was in step 2 (that is, you have to undo step 2)
5. Reverse rotate the axis-point pair which was done in step 1 (that is, you have to undo step 1)

To show that a matrix is orthonormal, you need to show that it is [*orthogonal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) (each row is independent of any other row and each column is independent of any other column) and that the length of each row (and column) is 1. Equivalently, a *square* matrix $Q$ is orthogonal if and only if

$$
Q^TQ = QQ^T = I
$$

where $Q^T$ is the [transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) of $Q$ and $I$ is the identity matrix. If you are really stuck, have a look at this proof https://math.stackexchange.com/a/537248/168764 (and this other answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/156742/168764), but, at this point, it should just be a matter of replacing $R_k(\theta)$ in the equation above and check that the equation holds.